# Download folder from SharePoint

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sharepoint, wget

I am trying to download from SharePoint. I am using wget --no-check-certificate --quiet --header 'Authorization: Bearer  -r 'https://(confidential).sharepoint.com/sites//_api/Web'/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents')' but getting no output, can someone please help to download the folder shared documents .

I tried using wget --no-check-certificate --quiet --header 'Authorization: Bearer  -r 'https://(confidential).sharepoint.com/sites//_api/Web'/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents')'. I want to download shared documents folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand: You're trying to download the contents (files and folders) of a SharePoint folder through scripting.

Assuming your only issue is the usage of the SharePoint REST Api (and you got your authentication covered), **there is no method in the SharePoint REST Api to download multiple files and even less recursively the contents of a folder.**

The call you are making (`_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('')`) should give you the properties of one folder (assuming you actually enter a server relative url (i.e `/sites/my-site/Shared Documents` and not what you put in your example)

To retrieve the contents of a file, it would rather be `_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('')/$value`.

So to do what you're trying to do, you would need to use the following calls recursively:

`_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('')/files?$select=ServerRelativeUrl` to get the files directly under a given folder

`_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('')/folders?$select=ServerRelativeUrl` to get the folders directly under a given folder

`_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('')/$value` to get the contents of a given file